# Qgis2web mouse cursor changing symbology

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-3

Hovering mouse cursor over polygon on QGIS created webpage changing symbology.

I´m have exported webpage from QGIS, thru qgis2web [plugin](https://github.com/tomchadwin/qgis2web/wiki). On settings I have checked "Highlight on hover". When I move cursor over polygon with complicated symbology (2x simple line, simple fill)(fig. 1), polygon is highlighted (fig.2). When I move out of polygon, symbology is changed and simplified, no line symbology.(fig.3). Same problem occur with polylines.

[image: Changing_symbology_fig_1_2_3]

When I don´t use "Highlight on hover" option, symbology doesn´t change.

Comment: Are you using the Leaflet or the OpenLayers export? Do both have the same issue?

Comment: Using Leaflet, result with OpenLayers is similar

Comment: Can you host an example somewhere? Tried to replicate the issues but it was working fine for me.

Comment: I uploaded original shp and qgis project with exported web. [link](https://www.uschovna.cz/zasilka/SEFFH42H8X4B4R9E-6A3)